# Dual SIM check internet connection issue

Tags: android, dual-sim

I use this code to check if internet network is on:

```
public boolean isNetworkOnline() {
        boolean status=false;
        try{
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                status= true;
            }else {
                netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
                if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    status= true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();  
            return false;
        }
        return status;

        }
```

The problem is that if you use internet 3g from the SIM 2, this says that you do not have internet connection on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean outcome = false;


        if (context != null) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

            for (NetworkInfo tempNetworkInfo : networkInfos) {

                if (tempNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    outcome = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return outcome;
    }
```